# Comparing two arrays of appointments and removing conflicts

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to generate available appointment times based on how many employees are working at a given time and how many appointment slots are already filled. Assume two employees are working. One from 4:30 - 7:00 and the other from 4:30 -7:30, and each appointment is 30 minutes long. That info is used to generate the `possibleAppointments` array below.

```
const possibleAppointments = [
    { time: '4:30 PM' },
    { time: '4:30 PM' },
    { time: '5:00 PM' },
    { time: '5:00 PM' },
    { time: '5:30 PM' },
    { time: '5:30 PM' },
    { time: '6:00 PM' },
    { time: '6:00 PM' },
    { time: '6:30 PM' },
    { time: '6:30 PM' },
    { time: '7:00 PM' },
];

const reservedAppointments = [
    { time: '05:00 PM' }, // ends at 5:30
    { time: '6:10 PM' }, // ends at 6:40
    { time: '6:10 PM' }, // ends at 6:40
];
```

I want to use the `possibleAppointments` and `reservedAppointments` arrays above to create an `availableAppointments` array which should look like the array below since the reserved times conflict with one of the 5:00 appointment time slots and both of the 6:00 and 6:30 appointment time slots:

```
// availableAppointments
[
  { time: '4:30 PM' },
  { time: '4:30 PM' },
  { time: '5:00 PM' },
  { time: '5:30 PM' },
  { time: '5:30 PM' },
  { time: '7:00 PM' },
]
```

Here is a Stackblitz of one thing I've tried: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7h58ga?file=src/app/app.component.ts

I've been banging my head against the wall for a long time. How do I re-write the logic in that stackblitz so that

```
availableAppointments === [
      { time: '4:30 PM' },
      { time: '4:30 PM' },
      { time: '5:00 PM' },
      { time: '5:30 PM' },
      { time: '5:30 PM' },
      { time: '7:00 PM' },
    ]
```

Comment: Please include the definition of `this.checkIfApptsOverlap`. Without it, it's impossible to determine the issue.

Comment: Here is a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7h58ga?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make this into a straightforward  `filter()` call but in order to account for the double appointments at a single time slot you will need to track which employee each available and reserved appointment belongs to. (Otherwise the single 5:00 reservation filters out both 5:00 possible appts.)

```
const possibleAppointments = [
  { time: '4:30 PM', empl: 1 },
  { time: '4:30 PM', empl: 2 },
  { time: '5:00 PM', empl: 1 },
  { time: '5:00 PM', empl: 2 },
  { time: '5:30 PM', empl: 1 },
  { time: '5:30 PM', empl: 2 },
  { time: '6:00 PM', empl: 1 },
  { time: '6:00 PM', empl: 2 },
  { time: '6:30 PM', empl: 1 },
  { time: '6:30 PM', empl: 2 },
  { time: '7:00 PM', empl: 1 },
];

const reservedAppointments = [
  { time: '05:00 PM', empl: 1 }, // ends at 5:30
  { time: '6:10 PM', empl: 1 }, // ends at 6:40
  { time: '6:10 PM', empl: 2 }, // ends at 6:40
];

const availableAppointments = this.possibleAppointments.filter(possibleAppt => {
  return !this.reservedAppointments.some(rAppt => (
    this.checkIfApptsOverlap(rAppt, possibleAppt) && possibleAppt.empl === rAppt.empl))
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It is fiendishly difficult to figure out time overlap based on an arbitrary string like `6:10pm`. I therefore strongly suggest that you first assign numeric range representations to your times. This will make your code cleaner and allow significant flexibility in the future. You could, for example, spit your day into 1440 minutes and assign a range of them to every time slot. Then it becomes a simple matter of finding overlaps between ranges. Well, the matter isn't in fact so simple because you can have multiple employees and appointments overlapping multiple slots (e.g. the 6:10 PM to 6:40 PM appointment)

So let's just assume for a minute that you have decided to heed my advice on the minute-range assignment and did it like this:

```
0:00 - 0:59 (0 - 59 minutes from start of day)
1:00 - 1:59 (60 - 119 minutes)
2:00 - 2:59 (120 - 179 minutes)
...
```

Getting to 4:30pm you're at:

```
16:30 - 17:00 (990 - 1019 minutes)
17:00 - 17:30 (1020 - 1049 minutes)
```

Further assuming you properly assigned minute representations to your *possible* and *reserved* appointment arrays, the code to get the available slot is mostly straightforward save for the tiny caveat to account for those aberrant appointments and multiple employees:

```js
const possibleAppointments = [
    { time: '4:30 PM', start_minutes: 990, end_minutes: 1019 },
    { time: '4:30 PM', start_minutes: 990, end_minutes: 1019 },
    { time: '5:00 PM', start_minutes: 1020, end_minutes: 1049 },
    { time: '5:00 PM', start_minutes: 1020, end_minutes: 1049 },
    { time: '5:30 PM', start_minutes: 1050, end_minutes: 1079 },
    { time: '5:30 PM', start_minutes: 1050, end_minutes: 1079 },
    { time: '6:00 PM', start_minutes: 1080, end_minutes: 1109  },
    { time: '6:00 PM', start_minutes: 1080, end_minutes: 1109  },
    { time: '6:30 PM', start_minutes: 1110, end_minutes: 1139 },
    { time: '6:30 PM', start_minutes: 1110, end_minutes: 1139 },
    { time: '7:00 PM', start_minutes: 1140, end_minutes: 1169 },
];

const reservedAppointments = [
    { time: '5:00 PM', start_minutes: 1020, end_minutes: 1049 }, // ends at 5:30
    { time: '6:10 PM', start_minutes: 1090, end_minutes: 1119 }, // ends at 6:40
    { time: '6:10 PM', start_minutes: 1090, end_minutes: 1119 }, // ends at 6:40
];



reservedAppointments.forEach(taken_slot => {
    const indexes_to_remove = [];
    const times_removed = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < possibleAppointments.length; i++){
        const ind = possibleAppointments.findIndex(item =>
            !times_removed.includes(item.time)  &&
            ((item.start_minutes >= taken_slot.start_minutes && item.start_minutes <= taken_slot.end_minutes) ||
            (item.end_minutes >= taken_slot.start_minutes && item.end_minutes <= taken_slot.end_minutes))
        )
        if(ind === -1)
            break
        else {
            indexes_to_remove.push(ind)
            times_removed.push(possibleAppointments[ind].time)
        }
    }

    for (let i = indexes_to_remove.length -1; i >= 0; i--)
        possibleAppointments.splice(indexes_to_remove[i], 1);
})

console.log(possibleAppointments)
```

Note that I directly modify the `possibleAppointments` array to turn it into the `availableAppointments` array you wanted. If you want to keep that variable intact, you can clone it with, say: `const availableAppointments = [...possibleAppointments]` and loop through `availableAppointments` instead.